# How can I get Zsh to display the RVM gemset?

Tags: shell, rvm, zsh

I'd like to have Zsh diplay the current RVM Ruby and gemset, for instance:

```
$ [ ethan@devlaptop ~/ ruby-1.9.3-p194@some_gemset ]
```

I've installed oh-my-zsh and I've activated the RVM plugin in my `~/.rvmrc` like this:

```
plugins=(git ruby rails3 rvm cap)
```

I checked that RVM is working as recommended in the docs:

```
type rvm | head -n 1
rvm is a shell function
```

In a theme file I have my prompt set up like this:

```
PROMPT='%{$fg[white]%}[ %n@%m%{$fg[cyan]%} %2c %{$reset_color%}${rvm-prompt} %{$fg[white]%}] %{$reset_color%}'
```

But the prompt just turns out to be this:

```
[ ethan@devlaptop ~ prompt ]
```

When I directly run `rvm-prompt` on the command line, it works as expected.

Any idea what I need to fix?

Answer (score 6):

It was a syntax error. I needed `$(rvm-prompt)` instead of `${rvm-prompt}`.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a bug. Bugs should be reported to the developer, not to S.O.

https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/issues/new

Comment: OK, I submitted it at the URL you provided.